# Use N'' style unicode characters in join conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which has unicode characters in it, which are local to Azeri_Latin_100_CI_AS. When I try to join two tables , but cannot get results. Example:

Assume two tables exists:

1. Task
2. Client

Both has Name fields. There are values that are identical , but cannot be joined like below:

```sql
select * from Task join Client on Task.Name = Client.Name
```

Example values:

```
'Kənan' = 'Kənan' - this does not join though they are identical.
```

When I use `N'Kənan'` in where condition, it gets result. But cannot use in join conditions.

Comment: Can't reproduce what you are saying in a fiddle. But have you just tried casting directly to nvarchar? Ex: cast(task.name as nvarchar(255)) = cast(client.name as nvarchar(255)) . Where 255 is whatever the max length of the original column.

Comment: Try to `collate` fields to the same encoding 
`select * from Task join Client on Task.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  = Client.Name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Comment: Show us the column definitions.

Comment: Can you post an sp_help on Task and Client tables?

Comment: What's the database's default collation? When you don't use National character literals (those prefixed with `N`) then the characters are mapped to a code page subject to the database's default collation, i.e.: `select 'Kənan'` usually returns `K?nan` because the U+0259 schwa character (`ə`) isn't included in the most commonly used collations based on the Windows-1252 code page.